# QGIS Multi-layer selector for real time digitizing

Tags: qgis, layers, digitizing

From a project with more than one layer that are in Editing mode, I would need a solution that allows to, in real time, select the layer I want to digitize.

The solution I would need would be, for example, in two steps:

1- Click in the map view to add a new feature.

2- Show a dialog window with a combo box to choose which layer to edit.

My question is to know if there is any plugin or core tool of QGIS that is prepared to make this kind of work.

Comment: Bearing in mind multiple layers can be in edit mode at the same time, is selecting a layer in the layer tree and then digitising a feature (native behaviour) not a viable workflow?

Comment: I understand what you mean. The project I'm working on involves capturing (digitizing) data by monitoring some TV action (motion) footage. I would like to avoid the step of to select a layer in the layer native tree and return to the map view (mouse displacement on the screen), and interact only with the map view. It is a matter of simplify, avoiding distractions, not losing information and saving time.

Comment: I see, that makes it a lot clearer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as smooth as a custom plugin, but the [Locator filter](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html#locator-bar) (at the left end of the status bar) could be used for this purpose.
[image: QGIS locator filter]

- Activate Locator by keyboard shortcut (default: `Ctrl+K`)
- Filter for layers by typing prefix (default: `l`) followed by a `space`.
- Start typing layer name, it brings up the closest match on the fly
- Hit `Enter` to set active layer

This way only the keyboard is used to select active layer, no cursor movement. `Add Feature` remains enabled through changing active layer, and it can also be tied to hotkey, so no need to click on that either.

Some more streamlining is also possible:

- Set the Locator's hotkey and its filter-for-layers prefix to the same letter, for example `L`. These won't conflict, because the first is a [keyboard shortcut](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#keyboard-shortcuts), the second is a [setting internal to the Locator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#locator-settings).
- If possible, use a very simple numerical prefix for all layers you want to use this way, like *1_layername*; *2_layername*, etc. This way, you can only type the number in the Locator after the prefix, and it will jump to the appropriate layer.

With the above streamlining, it would look like this in practice:

`L` `L` `space` `1` `Enter`

...Digitize

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand the 'Activate Locator' concept. From here I cannot reproduce the workflow you propose.
Could you add some screenshots that exemplifies each of the steps?

Comment: Added screenshot and links to the relevant parts of QGIS documentation, I hope it helps.